# Shopify - Different prices based on country

Tags: e-commerce, shopify

Does anyone here on stack know if it's possible, in Shopify, to use different prices for different countries/regions i.e. i want a product to cost 10€ in Europe but 10$ in North America?

1. Most important to know whether it's possible or not (trough out the shopflow)
2. Implementation advice would be appreciated

The geolocation part is not the problem here.

Comment: Wondering the same thing, all I can find is converters....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have different prices for different countries. If you want to do that, setup a shop per country, and price the inventory accordingly. You can use geolocation code to at least render the correct shop per country then, and thus present the pricing that makes sense for that country.

Answer (score 2):

You can work a turnaround where: depending on the IP of the user you show him a variant. You can have, lets say, one variant for EU customers/visitors and one variant for USA customers/visitors. With a tiny JavaScript and a call to an external API to know where the visitor is from, you can show him the right variant price.

Comment: What about stocks?

Comment: @LouisSerre then my workaround doesn't work. Check inventory locations new API to see if you can find any trick which would solve your concern

Answer (score -2):

it is possible. Check out this documentation
http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/currencies-and-translations/currencies/how-to-show-multiple-currencies

Comment: Thank you Abdul, I've seen that guide. But that does not allow me to have 10$ in US and 10€ in EU (or whatever price difference I'd like do have) because it's a currency converter, i can't decide the price on each market.